# Convergence almost and in law of a succession of random variables.

Tags: probability

I have a succession of random variables in $\Omega=[0,1]$ so this $X_n=(1-\omega)^n$. I want to prove the convergence almost and in law in $(\Omega,F,P)$ with $P=\delta_0$, $P={{1}\over{2}}\delta_0+{{1}\over{2}}\delta_1$ and $P=$Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

I know if a succession converges almost then converges in law so I prove the first.

I have convergence almost if there exists $\Omega_0 \in F : P(\Omega_0)=1$ and $\forall \omega \in \Omega_0 ,X_n(\omega)->X(\omega)$

If $$P=\delta_0 ,P(\{0\})=1 ; P((0,1])=0$$

$$P={{1}\over{2}}\delta_0+{{1}\over{2}}\delta_1,P(\{0\})={{1}\over{2}}=P((0,1])$$
 $$P=\lambda_{[0,1]},P=([a,b])=b-a,P(\{0\})=0,P=((0,1])=1$$

Comment: Hint: if $\omega \in (0,1]$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\omega)^n = 0$; if $\omega=0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\omega)^n = 1$. What are the probabilities of $(0,1]$ and $\{ 0 \}$ in each case?

Comment: Almost sure convergence, when it is in fact a full pointwise convergence, does not require to specify $P$. Here, for every $\omega$, $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$, for some random variable $X$ not so difficult to write down, end of proof for every $P$.

Comment: In the first case $P=\delta_0 ,P(X_n=1)=1,P(X_n=0)=0$ so $X_n$ almost converge to $X=1$.it's right?